# Getting MAC Address in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, mac-address

I am creating a windows 8 app. I have a requirement to save MAC address of my device but I could not find a way to get the MAC Address.

Can anybody help me out??

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/54883f27-fd1b-402c-aa14-264257434c32) says that it is not possible from a Windows Store app, by design.  The comments offer some alternatives:

- List of WIN32 and COM API that can be accessed from Windows Store apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br205757.aspx
- Use ASHWID a unique identifier, using this you can make per device logic for apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx
- Sample from Microsoft for download that successfully gets information like the system model and system manufacturer:﻿ http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169